# C# - Display a floor created with the Revit API

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0, revit-api

I have just developed a method that allows me to create a floor.
Being new to the Revit API, it seems to me that the floor I just created exists but is not yet visible on Revit.
So my question is the following: How do I make this floor visible in Revit?

I might be wrong, in which case I would be happy if you could explain the problem to me.

Thank you!

```
public Result CreateFloor(UIApplication uiapp)
        {
            UIDocument uiDoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
            Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices.Application app = uiapp.Application;
            Document doc = uiDoc.Document;

            using (Transaction transaction = new Transaction(doc))
            {

                if (transaction.Start("Create floor") == TransactionStatus.Started)
                {
                    XYZ[] points = new XYZ[3];
                    points[0] = new XYZ(0,0,0);
                    points[1] = new XYZ(0,10,0);
                    points[2] = new XYZ(10,0,0);

                    CurveArray curve = new CurveArray();

                    Line line1 = Line.CreateBound(points[0], points[1]);
                    Line line2 = Line.CreateBound(points[1],points[2]);
                    Line line3 = Line.CreateBound(points[2], points[0]);
                    curve.Append(line1);
                    curve.Append(line2);
                    curve.Append(line3);

                    Floor floor=doc.Create.NewFloor(curve, false);
                    return Result.Succeeded;
                }
                else
                {
                    transaction.RollBack();
                    return Result.Failed;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Commit your transaction after creating the Floor.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for raising that question, I struggled the first time I encountered it.

You need to add

```
transaction.Commit();
```

before `return Result.Succeeded;`